# How to redirect all console output to a GUI textbox?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I currently have a program that prints lines of text to the screen in various manners such as 'System.out.println()' statements and for loops the print all elements in an array to screen.

I am now adding a GUI to this program. My problem is that I want to print everything that prints to eclipse's console to a textbox in my GUI instead. Is this possible and if so how would I go about doing this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: True sqook, I did not see your edit, I had changed the original question.

Answer (score 22):

Check out this blog article, entitled [Redirecting System.out and System.err to JTextPane or JTextArea](http://unserializableone.blogspot.com/2009/01/redirecting-systemout-and-systemerr-to.html). It describes almost everything you need.

The basic idea is that you create your own specialized output stream. In your implementation of the `write()` methods, you call some code to append the new data to your text box. Then, you set this new output stream as your `System.out` by calling `System.setOut()` or `System.setErr()`.

**NOTE: that article is missing one thing. You need to [start your program in a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20938818/495796).**

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This site seems to have the things it wants to print to the textarea in the same class as the gui. I want to keep the classes seperate.

Comment: He corrected the problem of 2 threads. So the tutorial is correct now.

Answer (score 7):

An idea:

Create your own PrintStream that outputs everything to this textbox.
Then set this new PrintStream to be the [standard output](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)) stream like that:

```
System.setOut(myPrintStream());
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to give a bit more detail as to how I could implement this idea since the printing is happening in a seperate class? thanks.

Comment: Just look at the post given by theomega !