# How to redirect console content to a textArea in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm trying to get the content of console in a textArea in java.

For example if we have this code,

```
class FirstApp {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and I want to output the "Hello World" to a textArea, what actionPerformed do I have to choose?

Answer (score 10):

I found this simple solution:

First, you have to create a class to replace the standard output:

```
public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public CustomOutputStream(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        // redirects data to the text area
        textArea.append(String.valueOf((char)b));
        // scrolls the text area to the end of data
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
        // keeps the textArea up to date
        textArea.update(textArea.getGraphics());
    }
}
```

Then you replace standards as follows:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(50, 10);
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(textArea));
System.setOut(printStream);
System.setErr(printStream);
```

The problem is that all the outputs will be showed only in the text area.

Source with a sample: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/redirect-standard-output-streams-to-jtextarea

Comment: This is almost perfect, but whenever the console outputs the textarea flashed a bunch. Instead of appending, use `textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + String.valueOf((char)paramInt));` instead, it doesn't flash and flows like the original `System.out`.

Comment: You may have to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() for this to work.

Answer (score 8):

[Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) shows one solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to redirect `System.out` to a custom, observable subclass of `PrintStream`, so that each char or line added to that stream can update the content of the textArea (I guess, this is an AWT or Swing component)

The `PrintStream` instance could be created with a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, which would collect the output of the redirected `System.out`

Answer (score 3):

One of the way you can do it by setting the `System OutputStream` to a `PipedOutputStream` and connect that to a `PipedInputStream` that you read from to add text to your component, E.g

```
PipedOutputStream pOut = new PipedOutputStream();   
System.setOut(new PrintStream(pOut));   
PipedInputStream pIn = new PipedInputStream(pOut);  
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pIn));
```

Have u looked at the following link ? If not, then you must.

- [Print to textArea instead of console in eclipse ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564913/how-to-print-to-textarea-instead-of-console-in-eclipse)
- [Redirecting all console o/p to GUI textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564759/how-to-redirect-all-console-output-to-a-gui-textbox)
- [Simple java console - Swing based](http://www.comweb.nl/java/Console/Console.html)

Answer (score 1):

[like this http://img122.imageshack.us/img122/5692/dibujoof2.png](http://img122.imageshack.us/img122/5692/dibujoof2.png)

[Create Java console inside a GUI panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-the-panel)