# how to add the outputs from other class inside a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

i want to place my output from other class inside a JFrame heres the code:

inside main class

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    int choice;
    int g;
    String randomNo;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    randomNo=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter how many random no:");
    g=Integer.parseInt(randomNo);

    RandomAlgo rand=new RandomAlgo();
    int[] data=rand.randomNum(g);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Random numbers Are  : " + Arrays.toString(data));

    String randomChoice;
    randomChoice=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose Sorting algorithm: \n (1)Selection Sort \n (2)Insertion Sort \n (3)Bubble Sort \n (4)Quick Sort" );
    choice=Integer.parseInt(randomChoice);

    switch(choice){
      case 1:{
        SortingAlgo algo=new SortingAlgo();
        data=algo.selectionSort(data);
        break;
      }
      case 2:{
        SortingAlgo algo=new SortingAlgo();
        data=algo.InsertionSort(data);
        break;
      }
      case 3:{
        SortingAlgo algo=new SortingAlgo();
        data=algo.bubbleSort(data);
        break;
      }
      case 4:{
        SortingAlgo algo=new SortingAlgo();
        data=algo.quickSort(data);

      }
    }
  }
  public Main(){
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Sorted List");
    JLabel jdate=new JLabel("");
    frame.setSize(300,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }


}
```

and then here is my SortingAlgo class........................................................

```
  import java.util.Arrays;
public class SortingAlgo{
  public int[] selectionSort(int[] data){
    int lenD = data.length;
    int j = 0;
    int tmp = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<lenD;i++){
      j = i;
      for(int k = i;k<lenD;k++){
        if(data[j]>data[k]){
          j = k;
        }
      }
      tmp = data[i];
      System.out.println("\n"+ Arrays.toString(data));
      data[i] = data[j];
      data[j] = tmp;
    }
      return data;
  }
  public int[] InsertionSort(int[] data){
  int len = data.length;
  int key = 0;
  int i = 0;
  for(int j = 1;j<len;j++){
    key = data[j];

    i = j-1;

    while(i>=0 && data[i]>key){
      data[i+1] = data[i];
      i = i-1;
      data[i+1]=key;
       System.out.println("\n"+ Arrays.toString(data)); 
    }
  }
  return data;
  }

  public int[] bubbleSort(int[] data){
  int lenD = data.length;
  int tmp = 0;
  for(int i = 0;i<lenD;i++){

    for(int j = (lenD-1);j>=(i+1);j--){
      System.out.println("\n"+ Arrays.toString(data));
      if(data[j]<data[j-1]){
        tmp = data[j];

        data[j]=data[j-1];

        data[j-1]=tmp;


      }
    }  System.out.println("\n"+ Arrays.toString(data));

  }
  return data;
  }
  public int[] quickSort(int[] data){
    int lenD = data.length;
    int pivot = 0;
    int ind = lenD/2;
    int i,j = 0,k = 0;
    if(lenD<2){
      return data;
    }
    else{
      int[] L = new int[lenD];
      int[] R = new int[lenD];
      int[] sorted = new int[lenD];
      pivot = data[ind];
      for(i=0;i<lenD;i++){
        if(i!=ind){
          if(data[i]<pivot){
            L[j] = data[i];
            j++;
          }
          else{
            R[k] = data[i];
            k++;
          }
        }

      }
      int[] sortedL = new int[j];
      int[] sortedR = new int[k];
      System.arraycopy(L, 0, sortedL, 0, j);
      System.arraycopy(R, 0, sortedR, 0, k);
      sortedL = quickSort(sortedL);
      sortedR = quickSort(sortedR);
      System.arraycopy(sortedL, 0, sorted, 0, j);
      sorted[j] = pivot;
      System.arraycopy(sortedR, 0, sorted, j+1, k);
      System.out.println("\n"+ Arrays.toString(sorted));
      return sorted;
    }
  }
}
```

as for my random class.................................

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.*;
public class RandomAlgo { 

  public int[] randomNum(int g){ 
        Random rand = new Random();

        int[] randomNumbers = new int[g];

        for (int i = 0; i < g; i++) {
            int e = rand.nextInt(1000);
            randomNumbers[i] = e;

        }

        return randomNumbers;
    }

  }
```

my code is working in console. but im now i want to place the ouput of the sorted list inside a frame. and not on console.

Comment: What, exactly do you hope to output the content to?

Comment: i want the output for example i want to sort: 5 1 4 2 8 

i want the output inside Jframe would be like:

5 1 4 2 8
1 5 4 2 8
1 2 4 5 8
1 2 4 5 8

if i use selection sorting

Comment: In a text field, text area as labels as a single string or as seperate elements?

Comment: So, I would say you need some kind of container that is capable of taking you array, removing the old content and creating a new view of the elements.  You'll want to decouple this as best as you can...

Comment: thank you.  the output is fine in console. but im having hard time converting it in gui.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be redirect standard output (i.e. **System.out**) into a text area within JFrame

It is enough develop a Custom PrintStream and call

```
System.setOut( new MyCustomPrintStream() );
```

To have further details "[How to redirect console content to a textArea in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107629/how-to-redirect-console-content-to-a-textarea-in-java)"

Answer (score 0):

Regarding,

```
System.out.println("\n"+ Arrays.toString(data));
**//is this good? that i placed print here so i can show the ouput to the each sorting steps?**
```

No, that won't work well. println prints to the console not to a GUI. Your `selectionSort()` method returns an array of int already -- so why not simply use that? I'd get the array results from your selectionSort method and in the GUI, use a for loop to iterate through the array and print the results in your JTextArea.

```
switch(choice){
  case 1:{
    SortingAlgo algo=new SortingAlgo();
    data=algo.selectionSort(data);

    // you've got your sorted data here. 
    // put your for loop here to show it in your GUI

    break; 
  }
```

Comment: technically, that print is happening inside a loop, repeatedly, so I can see why it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a `JFrame`.

Create a `JPanel` and add a bunch of `JRadioButton`s to it.  These will act as you choices, `Selection Sort`, `Insertion Sort`, `Bubble Sort`, `Quick Sort`.  Add each of these to a `ButtonGroup` so that only button can be selected.

Add a `JTextField` to this panel, this will act as "random number length" value (you could also use a `JSpinner`, but let's not complicate things.

Add a `JButton` to the panel.  This will act as you "Sort" button, which will take the input and actually do the sorting.  Add an `ActionListener` to this button

Add this panel to the frame's `BorderLayout.WEST` position...

Create another `JPanel`, using a `GridLayout`.

To this, I would add two `JList`s, each inside their own `JScrollPane`s.  These will act as the unsorted and sorted lists.

Add this panel to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position of the frame.

When the user clicks the button, you will need to determine which `JRadioButton` is selected, get the text from the `JTextField`, convert this to an `int` (`Integer.parseInt(text)`).

Generate the list of random numbers, add these to the first `JList`, perform your sort, then add the result to the second `JList`.

Take a read through...

- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)
- [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- [Using Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

For more details...