# Java Running number in textarea

Tags: java

I have a Jframe, inside the frame i have a textarea.

```
public void count() {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 99999; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    jTextarea.setText("i: " + i);
    }

}
```

the message displayed in the textarea is only the last number.
how to display the system.out message in the textarea

Comment: check following solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107629/how-to-redirect-console-content-to-a-textarea-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're resetting the value in the `jTextArea` on every iteration. Instead, you need to concat all the messages together and then set it to your `TextArea`. You can do that using a `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
for (i = 0; i < 99999; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    msg.append("i: " + i + "\n");
}
jTextarea.setText(msg.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Well there isn't any easy way to send the output of `System.out.println` to the `JTextArea`, but what you should probably do instead is simply concatenate your output to the `JTextArea`'s text, like this:

```
jTextArea.append(i + "\n");
```

Comment: using this method it will flash display all the value at once, how to display it like System.out.println where value display 1 by 1 into the textarea

Answer (score 2):

[`setText`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) does just that, sets the current text value to what ever you specify.

Instead, you could try using [`append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29), which will append the text you supply to the end of the `JTextArea`'s `Document`, for example...

```
jTextarea.append("i: " + i + "\n");
```