# Show on a window (awt/swing) what I system.out.prinlt()

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, awt

I have a void method that prints some stuff. Can (swing)TextField be filled with the content of my print, somehow? Or should I use something different?

if my method prints:

```
Hello
how
are
you?
```

I would like to show on the window, exactly that. Thank you.

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        label.setText(instance.voidMethodThatPrints());
    }
}
```

It does not work cause setText takes a string, so I was trying to ask you if there's a faster way to make it work.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried already? You can use a TextFields setText() method to display text.

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE look at the code, it clearly won't work

Comment: can you change the void method to return a String? The only other thing I can think of is you could change System.out to use a custom PrintWriter as in Kayamans answer. Heres a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564913/how-to-print-to-textarea-instead-of-console-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `textArea.append(text)`? Call it with appropriate arguments and get what you need.

Comment: textArea too requires a String, I'm talking about a void mathod. Look at the code on the top.

Comment: I am sorry, @Matt I have no idea what do you want. Do you want a void method that "prints" something into textarea? But text area is not a output stream. You can (if you want) implement `PrintWriter` that in fact calls `textarea.append()`. The question remains here is "why"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.setOut(PrintWriter pw)` to redirect the standard output. However you'll have to write some additional logic to make it go to a text area (since there's no `setOut(JTextArea jt)` method).

Edit: This approach is not recommended for your situation. The correct approach in your case would be to redesign your code, such as suggested by `I-LOVE-2-REVIVE` in the comments.