# Terminal Runner for javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

How to get graphical terminal in javafx pane.  In my project, I have debug button is there,click that button graphical terminal open in my pane.if any package is there are give to idea, how to make are bind terminal in my pane[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly then you want to forward all the terminal data to a textArea/Pane. You can use JavaFX UI inplace of swing. Please follow the following link :

[How to redirect all console output to a GUI textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564759/how-to-redirect-all-console-output-to-a-gui-textbox)

For using the whole terminal inside the pane, you may consider using "[Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)" and "[Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)" to get the behaviour that you desire from a console.

You may also find this intersting

http://code.google.com/p/dragonconsole/wiki/DragonConsole

Comment: ok Thanks, i will try this solution but I am not redirect console output.I need communicate terminal in pane

Comment: You need the whole terminal inside a pane ?