# Java - Run program in background on Button click

Tags: java, sockets, user-interface

I got this gui which has 2 buttons start and stop server
When I press start the server needs to start running and if i close the GUI it should have no effect  on the running of the server the server will only be stopped if i open the gui and press stop server
What is the best way to do so?
I was thinking about creating a new console application, but i have no idea how to do so while running a program.

This is what i tried:

```
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                Process process = runTime.exec("java -classpath .\\bin Server.RunServer");

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: are you using Swing?

Comment: no i use swt but thats not the main problem the thing is how you do something like i mentioned above

Comment: Here is question with pretty much same issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820672/can-i-create-java-gui-application-which-can-run-other-java-programs-in-it/29822060#29822060

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I launch a completely independent process from a Java program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931536/how-do-i-launch-a-completely-independent-process-from-a-java-program)

Comment: That answers shows sort of 'deprecated' way to achieve this with Runtime.exe

Comment: It wont seem to help me those example even the process builder

Comment: you are not using processbuilder correctly in your question.

Comment: what do you  mean I tried something like this      ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java.exe","-cp","bin","Server.RunServer");
     try {
     Process process = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: no i rather not do so because i want to always change it and keep it as so . is the only way is to make it a jar file?

Comment: Does Server.RunServer include main method ?

Comment: yes it does contain a main class but when i run the code it wont seem to do something

Comment: Have you set JAVA_HOME environment variable ? Could you try to write full path to Server.RunServer

Comment: When saying full path you mean something like:C:\Users\Akok\61\Playground\src\Server\ServerWindow.java

Comment: i meant full path to external application you are trying to execute with process builder. Yeah, in that form

Comment: my friend,can you please help me write the correct code? The file is RunServer it is in Server package and the path is as specified above